# .htaccess code to block UserAgents containing Windows 2001-2009 in names

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to block useragents which contain following in their names:

```
Windows 2001
Windows 2002
Windows 2003
Windows 2004
Windows 2005
Windows 2006
Windows 2007
Windows 2008
Windows 2009
```

I'll use following code in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Windows\ 200[1-9].* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Is the above code correct or is there any other correct form of the code to do this?

Comment: And exactly why are you doing this? There's no Windows 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007 or 2009, and even Windows 2003 and 2008 + R2 are introduced in the user-agent with their Windows NT version: `Windows NT 5.2` (2003, 2003 R2), `Windows NT 6.0` (Windows Vista, Windows Serer 2008) or `Windows NT 6.1` (Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2).

Comment: I'm getting some hits from these useragents which are fake. That's why I'm trying to block them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Windows\ 200[1-9].* [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
> ```

What you have should work OK. It could be tidied a bit...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\ 200[1-9] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Assuming you already have a `RewriteEngine On` directive somewhere. Or, some might prefer to explicitly show whitespace using the short-hand character class `\s` instead of an escaped space `\`, since spaces can be hard to read (and hard to write here!). Alternatively, quote the *CondPattern* instead of escaping the space. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Windows 200[1-9]" [NC]
```

Whatever works for you.

With regex, you don't need `.*` before and after a pattern if you want to express that the user-agent *contains* the pattern. That is default regex behaviour. And if you use the `F` flag, you don't need the `L` flag - it is implied. And no need to capture the `RewriteRule` if its not being used. So, instead of `^(.*)$` you can simply write `.*` or `^` (my preference).

If the string being matched is *always* "Windows" (with a capital "W" and lowercase for the rest) then you don't need the `NC` flag.

**UPDATE:**

> what's the difference between `^(.*)$`, `.*` and `^` in using in RewriteRule statement?

`^(.*)$` - This explicitly grabs everything between the start and end of the string (URL-path) and saves this in the `$1` backreference to be used later (if you wish). `^` is the start-of-string anchor and `$` is the end of string anchor.

`.*` - This matches *everything*. Any character 0 or more times.

`^` - This is simply a start of string anchor, so it matches *anything*.

In the above `RewriteRule`, we don't care what the requested URL is, we are only interested in the User-Agent, so matching *anything* is sufficient.

---

Alternatively, use mod_setenvif instead. In some ways this would be preferable to using mod_rewrite (above). (Although I believe you did something like this using `SetEnvIf` in another question and it didn't work for you for some reason?)

```
BrowserMatch "Windows 200[1-9]" bad_agent
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not env bad_agent
</RequireAll>
```

Assuming Apache 2.4+. This would be used in combination with any other blocking rules you have (so, therefore, might require modifying).

Use `BrowserMatchNoCase` if you need a case-insensitive match.

> `BrowserMatch` is a special case of the `SetEnvIf` directive that sets environment variables conditionally on the `User-Agent` HTTP request header.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html

Comment: Thanks. I did the same as suggested by you. Can you please describe what's the difference between `^(.*)$`, `.*` and `^` in using in `RewriteRule` statement?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used only `^` and it worked.